# GNU Octave not opening after installation on Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, octave

When I installed Octave version 5.2.0_1 installer.exe and ran it on the PC, the installation started and software got installed. It created two shortcuts on the desktop named - GNU Octave(CLI) and GNU Octave(GUI). After clicking any of the two nothing opens.

I then thought to check the compatibility of the software with Windows 10, but the Windows compatibility troubleshooter did not recognise any such software on the PC. I have no clue on what to do further. Please help regarding this.

Comment: check if the Antivurus has falsely detected some shared lib as infected. There were some AV false report mentioned in the past on 5.2 and some needed DLL were quarantined

Comment: Would it work if I installed any previous versions? such as - version 5.1 , 4. ..?

Comment: it seems only 5.2 had the issue with some AV

Comment: there have been a handful of odd, hard to naildown startup problems in windows. most are due to local conflicts with security software.  Sometimes a reboot, uninstall/reinstall, deleting user profile octave files help.  Otherwise you can try the zip package instead of the exe installer, making sure you follow the instructions at: http://wiki.octave.org/Octave_for_Microsoft_Windows

Comment: regarding the recent issues with false positives - while the files have been whitelisted with most major AV companies, it's possible.  the main culprit was libsqlite3-0.dll, it should be located at \Octave\octave-5.2.0-w64\mingw64\bin\libsqlite3-0.dll, so if you're missing that file it may indicate that this was your problem. Most often this file missing just produced very obvious error messages, though, not 'nothing', so I'm doubting that's the issue.

Comment: nope, there is a libsqlite3-0.dll file in the same location. That may not be the problem. The problem I think is with the Microsoft windows based script host. Is there any other way anyone can suggest? should I download any previous versions? Or the problem may persist even then?

Comment: Does running \Octave\Octave-5.2.0\mingw64\bin\octave.bat at least run the command line version ?